# App Error <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

Nov 16 12:34:28 123456789.local iDraw Cross[2926] : CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means surface you are trying to use has zero surface size.

Check this out:
[CGContext invalid context 0x0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508048/cgcontext-invalid-context-0x0)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly nothing. It depends on the circumstances under which you are seeing the message. There are some Simulator bugs that can cause this message; run the app on a device and see if you get it then. If not, then forget about it. Otherwise, show your code if you want specific help.

Comment: With the 7.0.3 iPad simulator it seems to show this for me almost every time a text field becomes first responder. It's very irritating.

Comment: Yes, That is what happens for me too.  I cannot get it to do anything now and I don't know what to do.  I also am not sure what to post for my source as I don't want too much public as its on the app store.